# Changing winning criterion in a question

Tags: discussion, editing, winning-criteria

I recently posted a question to [codegolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/34898/the-golf-resort?noredirect=1#comment75190_34898) which did not have a well formulated win criterion. However, I did receive some answers to the question.

Because the question is on hold due to **"off-topic"**, and further *"Questions without an objective primary winning criterion.."*, I guess I should try to save the question by changing the win criterion. However, as there are answers to the question already, these might be invalidated by changing the win criterion.

What should I do? Leave the question to die, change the win criterion, or are there some other approach I should use?

Comment: That wasn't the only problem with the question. See xnor's comment on it, and mine.

Comment: I know it wasn't the only problem with the question. However, this is what I don't know the answer to. I could improve the clarity of the question etc., but what do I do about the win criterion? Is it ok to change after people have given answers?